# Maven - Spring - Liquibase includeAll not work

Tags: java, spring, maven, liquibase

If you run liquibase in 3.5.1 through cmd everything it works correctly. If I run it through spring boot fits on includeAll, I tried to enter various ways nothing helped.

Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sequence/'

Directory exist and not empty (files exist).

```
   2016-07-26 08:29:21,949 [main] DEBUG s.t.e.c.c.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Liquibase
    2016-07-26 08:29:23,707 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.c.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer@1f7853af: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DAOAuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.config.authc.DAOAuthenticationConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.repository.admin.AdmUserRepository sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.security.UserDetailsService.admUserRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'admUserRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#671f545b' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#671f545b': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [sk/trilobit/eskn/cskn/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sequence/'
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DAOAuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.config.authc.DAOAuthenticationConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.repository.admin.AdmUserRepository sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.security.UserDetailsService.admUserRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'admUserRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#671f545b' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#671f545b': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [sk/trilobit/eskn/cskn/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sequence/'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        ...
        at sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.Application.main(Application.java:90) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DAOAuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.config.authc.DAOAuthenticationConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.repository.admin.AdmUserRepository sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.security.UserDetailsService.admUserRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'admUserRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#671f545b' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#671f545b': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [sk/trilobit/eskn/cskn/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sequence/'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DAOAuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.config.authc.DAOAuthenticationConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.repository.admin.AdmUserRepository sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.security.UserDetailsService.admUserRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'admUserRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#671f545b' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#671f545b': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [sk/trilobit/eskn/cskn/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sequence/'
        at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164) ~[spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1412) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:982) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:616) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        ... 58 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DAOAuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.config.authc.DAOAuthenticationConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.repository.admin.AdmUserRepository sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.security.UserDetailsService.admUserRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'admUserRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#671f545b' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#671f545b': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [sk/trilobit/eskn/cskn/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sequence/'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.getWebSecurityConfigurers(AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.java:52) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:112) ~[spring-expression-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129) ~[spring-expression-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49) ~[spring-expression-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:342) ~[spring-expression-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120) ~[spring-expression-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:242) ~[spring-expression-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:161) ~[spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        ... 62 common frames omitted
        ...
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [sk/trilobit/eskn/cskn/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sequence/'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:824)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at sk.trilobit.eskn.cskn.Application.main(Application.java:90)
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sequence/'
        at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:27)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:229)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:434)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:391)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sequence/'
        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.includeAll(DatabaseChangeLog.java:445)
        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:349)
        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:282)
        at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:25)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sequence/'
        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.includeAll(DatabaseChangeLog.java:438)
        ... 25 more
```

Please help me :)

Comment: it seems that the directory sequence is missing. The exception says so. try to create it and run again. For a better understanding it would be helpfull to see your spring boot configuration

Comment: Not sure it is a spring issue - there's a bug on version 3.5.1 - try running the same code on version 3.4.2

Comment: same happend to me when upgrading to spring-boot-starter-parent 1.4.0-RELEASE

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrading to 3.5.3 version.

Comment: See https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2863. States that it is fixed with 3.5.2, but it is not (still same behavior with spring-boot 1.4.2 - liquibase 3.5.3)