# Liquibase includeAll being ignored

Tags: spring, maven, migration, liquibase

The `includeAll` tag in liquibase is not working at all, at least in the project I've been trying to use it for. 
**My environment:**

- Spring 1.5.4
- Maven 3.5.4
- Liquibase Core 3.5.3

**Liquibase configuration** (stored under src/main/resources/)
db/changelog-master.yaml:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - preConditions:
    - dbms:
        type: h2
  - includeAll:
      path: db/changelog/changes
```

Directory src/main/resources/db/changlog/changes consists of two test changelog files:
*00-a-sample_changelog.yml*

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: JonDoe
      comment: "Test changeset"
      preConditions:
        - onFail: WARN
        - not:
          - tableExists:
              schemaName: public
              tableName: liquid-test-jd
      changes:
      - createTable:
          tableName: liquid-test-jd
          columns:
          - column:
              name: test_id
              type: number
          - column:
              name: test_time
              type: timestamp
```

*00-b-sample_changelog_cleanup.yml*

```
databaseChangeLog:
      - changeSet:
          id: 2
          author: JonDoe
          comment: Cleanup test changeset
          preConditions:
            - onFail: WARN
            - tableExists:
                 schemaName: public
                 tableName: liquid-test-jd
          changes:
          - dropTable:
              schemaName: public
              tableName: liquid-test-jd
```

This configuration just does not seem to work. Nothing is logged, the DATABASECHANGELOG table is empty. Even when I tried with only the first file being present in directory (the `createTable` one), there was no sign of new table being created.
When I tried with separate `include` statements inside `db.changelog-master` however, it worked perfectly.

I know that this question refers to [Maven - Spring - Liquibase includeAll not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582631/maven-spring-liquibase-includeall-not-work) but symptoms are slightly different. I hope mods will also find this as not being a duplicate

Comment: Have you seen this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41678616/332248) and the related pull request [here](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/709). The pull request was accepted and the problem seems to be in liquibase 3.5.3. Maybe updating liquibase will help...

Comment: Thanks for the link, I haven't seen it before :) As for the liquibase version - I updated version to 3.6.2 - it did not work